# Providing an API to a Portable Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, mvccontrib

I've managed to get Portable Areas working greatly and I think it's a very clean solution to allowing drop in sections for a web application.

One thing that I feel is missing that I've not come across in any tutorials I've found is the ability to provide the Portable Area an interface that it can use as an API.

I want to do this as I want to integrate the area completely into the context of the running application as a plugin vs a completely self contained area that runs in concert with the application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the purpose of the IApplicationBus. See http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2009/11/02/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-part-2/